# Reshape to combine and transpose

Tags: r, reshape

With

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:2, rep(6,2)), treat=rep(rep(101:102, c(3,3)),2),
                 flavor=c(13,7,28,15,5,21,32,14,27,24,15,17))

df
   id treat flavor
1   1   101     13
2   1   101      7
3   1   101     28
4   1   102     15
5   1   102      5
6   1   102     21
7   2   101     32
8   2   101     14
9   2   101     27
10  2   102     24
11  2   102     15
12  2   102     17
```

I've molten the data:

```
df.melt <- melt(df, measure.var = "flavor")

df.melt
   id treat variable value
1   1   101   flavor    13
2   1   101   flavor     7
3   1   101   flavor    28
4   1   102   flavor    15
5   1   102   flavor     5
6   1   102   flavor    21
7   2   101   flavor    32
8   2   101   flavor    14
9   2   101   flavor    27
10  2   102   flavor    24
11  2   102   flavor    15
12  2   102   flavor    17
```

To cast `df.melt`, I need my result looks like the following with variable `flavor` summed up for each `id` but also summed up according to each type of `treat` but transposed to the column:

```
df.cast
   id flavor_total treat_101 treat_102
1   1           89        48        41
2   2          129        73        56
```

Is this possible to do this with `cast`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use cast, maybe this helps:

```
> dfmc <- cast( df.melt, id ~ treat, sum )
> dfmc
  id 101 102
1  1  48  41
2  2  73  56

> dfmc$total <- rowSums( dfmc )
> dfmc
  id 101 102 total
1  1  48  41    89
2  2  73  56   129
```

Comment: Thx. It's actually my data is a lot more complicated than the example so it may not be appropriate to simply add another column with the total. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: You could try `cast( df.melt, id ~ treat, sum, margins = TRUE )` - or provide the real structure of your data...

Comment: with the treat margin only, `reshape2::dcast( df.melt, id ~ treat, sum, margins = "treat")`